# Tokudb and Fractal trees Index

Tags: database, mariadb, tokudb

I have a doubt regarding the use of fractal trees index in my tables.
I create table specifing the TokuDB engine

```
CREATE TABLE `My_table` (
...
) ENGINE=TokuDB
```

Documentation says: "TokuDB uses a particular data structure called fractal trees, which is optimized for data that do not entirely fit memory."

But if I perform this query

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `My_table`
```

all indexes retreived for my table have index_type = BTREE

So... ...is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, even though it says BTREE that is just a label.

You can double check with "show create table My_table;". If it shows "engine=TokuDB" then it's using Fractal Tree indexes.